# Show loading screen before dynamically created PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I have a view that is, instead of returning a `View()`, is returning a dynamically created PDF and then showing the PDF in a new tab. I'm not saving the PDF anywhere, or storing it anywhere. What I would like to do is have a loading screen show up while the PDF is being created. Can this be done?

```
public ActionResult SolicitorActionReport_Load(SolicitorActionParamsViewModel viewModel) {
    var cultivationModel = new CultivationModel(viewModel, ConstituentRepository, CampaignRepository);
    var cultivationData = cultivationModel.GetCultivationActivityData();
    var reportParamModel = new List<ReportParamModel>
                                   {new ReportParamModel {AgencyName = SelectedUserAgency.AgencyName, StartDate = viewModel.StartDate, EndDate = viewModel.EndDate}};

    var reportToRun = "ActionDateCultivationReport";
    if (viewModel.SortActionBy == SolicitorActionReportSortType.Constituent) {
        reportToRun = "ConstituentCultivationReport";
    } else if (viewModel.SortActionBy == SolicitorActionReportSortType.Solicitor) {
        reportToRun = "SolicitorCultivationReport";
    }

    return FileContentPdf("Constituent", reportToRun, cultivationData, reportParamModel, new List<FundraisingAppealMassSummary>(), new List<FundraisingAppealPortfolioSummary>());
}



public FileContentResult FileContentPdf(string folder, string reportName, object dataSet,object reportParamModel,object appealMassDataSet, object appealPortfolioDataSet) {
    var localReport = new LocalReport();
    localReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/bin/Reports/" + folder + "/rpt" + reportName + ".rdlc");
    var reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource(reportName + "DataSet", dataSet);

    var reportParamsDataSource = new ReportDataSource("ReportParamModelDataSet", reportParamModel);
    var reportParamsDataSourceMass = new ReportDataSource("FundraisingAppealMassSummaryDataSet", appealMassDataSet);
    var reportParamsDataSourcePortfolio = new ReportDataSource("FundraisingAppealPortfolioSummaryDataSet", appealPortfolioDataSet);

    #region Setting ReportViewControl

    localReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
    localReport.DataSources.Add(reportParamsDataSource);
    localReport.DataSources.Add(reportParamsDataSourceMass);
    localReport.DataSources.Add(reportParamsDataSourcePortfolio);

    localReport.SubreportProcessing += (s, e) => { e.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource); };

    string reportType = "pdf";
    string mimeType;
    string encoding;
    string fileNameExtension;
    //The DeviceInfo settings should be changed based on the reportType             
    //http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155397.aspx             
    string deviceInfo = "<DeviceInfo><OutputFormat>PDF</OutputFormat></DeviceInfo>";
    Warning[] warnings;
    string[] streams;
    byte[] renderedBytes;
    //Render the report             
    renderedBytes = localReport.Render(reportType, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out fileNameExtension, out streams, out warnings);

    #endregion

    return File(renderedBytes, mimeType);
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this without either saving the file on the server, passing JSON and building the PDF using some javascript library or loading it within an iframe.. You could also add a loading gif to the page if the reqest returned to that tab instead of returning to _blank.

Comment: you can get close to your desired effect with [jquery.fileDownload.js Library](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/). They provide an [ASP.NET MVC 3 demo](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload/tree/master/src) as well.

Comment: You can build a Progress Bar with SignalR: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh852586.aspx

Comment: I have seen it in SharePoint `SPLongOperation` see if you can find something here.
it appears as in this [image](http://lh5.ggpht.com/_o7Td6KCGNTA/TLQdqbf3ONI/AAAAAAAAAkY/GGs1IgOblls/image_thumb%5B1%5D.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm not saving the PDF anywhere, or storing it anywhere. What I would like to do is have a loading screen show up while the PDF is being created. Can this be done?

### Short Answer

**No**, not in a new tab.

---

The main problem with what you're trying to do is the lack of power you have when it comes to controlling the browser. Specifically, when you tell an anchor to open its hyperlink in a new tab (ie `target="_blank"`). There are hacky ways around this that generally are just going to frustrate your user because you're changing behavior that they might be dependent/relying on.

### Workaround

You can get very close to your desired outcome by using this [jQuery File Download plugin](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/) ([view a demo](http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/)). Basically, it manipulates an `iframe` to queue a download. This makes it possible to show a loading `div` while also keeping the user on the active page (not directing them to another tab). Then, the user can click the downloaded PDF which will most-likely open in a new tab (view compatible browsers [here](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/compatible-web-browsers-pdfmaker-applications.html)).

---

If you decide to use this plugin, here are the steps to applying it:

1. [Download](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload/blob/master/src/Scripts/jquery.fileDownload.js) the plugin `js` source and include it in your `Scripts`.
2. Include the `FileDownloadAttribute` class provided in the plugin MVC Demo:

   ```
   [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)] 
   public class FileDownloadAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
   {
       public FileDownloadAttribute(string cookieName = "fileDownload", string cookiePath = "/")
       {
           CookieName = cookieName;
           CookiePath = cookiePath;
       }

       public string CookieName { get; set; }

       public string CookiePath { get; set; }

       /// <summary>
       /// If the current response is a FileResult (an MVC base class for files) then write a
       /// cookie to inform jquery.fileDownload that a successful file download has occured
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="filterContext"></param>
       private void CheckAndHandleFileResult(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
       {
           var httpContext = filterContext.HttpContext;
           var response = httpContext.Response;

           if (filterContext.Result is FileResult)
               //jquery.fileDownload uses this cookie to determine that a file download has completed successfully
               response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie(CookieName, "true") { Path = CookiePath });
           else
               //ensure that the cookie is removed in case someone did a file download without using jquery.fileDownload
               if (httpContext.Request.Cookies[CookieName] != null)
               {
                   response.AppendCookie(new HttpCookie(CookieName, "true") { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1), Path = CookiePath });
               }
       }

       public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
       {
           CheckAndHandleFileResult(filterContext);

           base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
       }
   }
   ```

   <sub>[github source](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload/blob/master/src/Common/FileDownloadAttribute.cs)</sub>
3. Apply the `FileDownload` attribute to your `ActionResult` method:

   ```
   [FileDownload]
   public ActionResult SolicitorActionReport_Load(SolicitorActionParamsViewModel viewModel) {
       ...

       return FileContentPdf("Constituent", reportToRun, cultivationData, reportParamModel, new List<FundraisingAppealMassSummary>(), new List<FundraisingAppealPortfolioSummary>());
   }
   ```
4. Include the necessary markup in the `View` to which you'll be linking to the report:

   ```
   <a class="report-download" href="/Route/To/SolicitorActionReport">Download PDF</a>
   ```
5. Attach an event handler to the `report-download` anchor:

   ```
   $(document).on("click", "a.report-download", function () {
       $.fileDownload($(this).prop('href'), {
           preparingMessageHtml: "We are preparing your report, please wait...",
           failMessageHtml: "There was a problem generating your report, please try again."
       });
       return false; //this is critical to stop the click event which will trigger a normal file download!
   });
   ```

You can view working demos at http://jqueryfiledownload.apphb.com/. There is also a demo that uses pre-styled jQuery UI modals to "*prettify*" the user experience.

You can also download the demo ASP.NET MVC solution from [johnculviner / jquery.fileDownload](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload)  github to see all of this working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two choices:

1. Redirect to a "loading" page with fancy GIF spinners, then direct the request to the PDF (this would work if the PDF take a little server time to generate - the visitor would be looking at a loading page while waiting for next page to load)

or

1. Use an iFrame: load a page that has an iframe.  This page can overlay a spinning GIF and loading message while the iFrame loads the PDF itself.  Note: you could make the iframe 100% width and height